# Can I add multiple transition properties to one state in "Angular Animations"

Tags: angular, animation

I have this  trigger

```
 trigger('hello',[

          state('in',style({opacity: "1", marginTop:'0px'})), 
          state('out',style({opacity: "0", marginTop:'50px'})),

          transition('*=>*',animate('300ms 200ms ease-in'))

    ]),
```

Can I add multiple transition properties to one state?

```
// for marginTop    
animate('300ms 200ms ease-in')

//for opacity
animate('100ms 0ms ease-out');
```

Answer (score 4):

In short: Yes, you can, but it won't execute at the same time.

Add multiple `animate` methods to the `transition` method:

```
transition('*=>*', [
        animate(300, style({ marginTop: '0px' })),
        animate(100, style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
```

The animation gets executed 1 by 1. So the `marginTop` will execute first and when that's done, the `opacity` will execute

Comment: i have same question.
but i need both animation to start at the same time for material motion choreography

Answer (score 1):

i think the answer is by using `group()` function

https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences#parallel-animation-using-group-function

```
transition('*=>*', [
  animate('300ms 200ms ease-in', style({ marginTop: '0px' })),
  animate('100ms 0ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 1 }))
])
```

Comment: I think you meant to actually use the group function here